# Multiplying by zero causes inf or nan during training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to build a neural network with skip connections. Some times however I want to turn them off i.e. they should still be there (for shape reasons), but I don't want any signal to be conveyed.

E.g. I want something like this:

```
for i, num_layers in reversed(list(enumerate(layers))):
    ...
    if skip_connection_list is not None:
        skip_connection = skip_connection_list[i]
        if self.config.skip_skip:
            skip_connection = tf.multiply(skip_connection,0)
        stack = tf.concat([l, skip_connection], axis=-1)
```

When I try to train this I get the following warning

> `E tensorflow/core/kernels/check_numerics_op.cc:157] abnormal_detected_host @0x10478c10a00 = {1, 0} LossTensor is inf or nan`

Using another number, e.g. `1`, does not cause this issue. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: you could use a small number such as 1e-06

Comment: That is a bad idea, as the network might still learn to propagate information through this way, and when the number is changed back to 1 it would be a giant number.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem can be solved by simply assigning `skip_connection` to the zero vector. This might be useful for others as well, but this solution is very clumsy, so I will leave the question unanswered for now.

```
for i, num_layers in reversed(list(enumerate(layers))):
    ...
    if skip_connection_list is not None:
        if self.config.skip_skip:
            skip_connection = tf.zeros_like(skip_connection_list[i])
        else:            
            skip_connection = skip_connection_list[i]
        stack = tf.concat([l, skip_connection], axis=-1)
```